# SQL request truncated

Tags: mysql, sql, request, truncated

I've got a little problem with a sql request:

my $sql resquest ( result of echo $sql ):

```
INSERT INTO match (id, id_match, login, real_login, reponse, date) VALUES (NULL, '11', 'CaptainRida', 'rbikitar', 'oui', '2014-06-07')
```

and the error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'match (id, id_match, login, real_login, reponse, date) VALUES
>   (NULL, '11', 'Capt' at line 1

the sql request is truncated at 'login'. always 4 characters and BAM truncated.

can anyone help me, I have THE SAME SQL RESQUEST with another table ( exactly the same except rencontre instead of match and id_rencontre instead of id_match)

the "rencontre" request works great and the "match" request is truncated in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MATCH` is a MySQL [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Enclose it in backticks:

```
insert into `match` (id, id_match, ...
```

Or, consider changing the name of the table to not use a reserved word (recommended).

Comment: ok, I was thinking about a shit like this in the bus, i will fix this, thank you.